# DropDownList in custom Grid popup editor - filter datasource

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm using a custom popup editor in a detail grid (several fields are using data attribute initialization).

One of the fields is a Kendo DropDownList, but I need the options in the list to be filtered based on the value of one of the fields in the currently expanded master row.

I've managed a buggy workaround by setting a global variable when a master row is expanded and then filtering the dropdownlist's datasource using a function call on the `open` event.

I'm sure there must be a better way to do this. Is it possible to specify a datasource filter using data attribute initialization -- I can't see anything in the docs for this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Missed the obvious...

I just needed to filter the datasource for the drop down list in the grid's `edit` event.